# How to save an array or object to be used in other runs

Tags: java, file, memory

I'm working with a sensor that taking data and giving it to me whenever I call on it. I want to collect 1 minute of data in an arraylist and then save it to a file or something so that I can analyze it at a different time.

So I have something like this:

```
ArrayList<DataObject> data = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
public void onUpdate(DataObject d) { //being called by my sensor every second
    data.add(d);
}
```

I want to save the ArrayList data to a file to my computer so that I can later feed it into a different program and use it there.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save these as CSV files, they'll be easily exportable and importable, even to Excel (which may be of value for doing further work or passing on results).

Check out [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#what-is-opencsv) and in particular [this entry in the FAQ](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#can-I-write) relating to writing the data out.

e.g.

```
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), ',');
 // feed in your array (or convert your data to an array)
 String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#");
 writer.writeNext(entries);
 writer.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just output the values to a file with something as a delimiter between the values, then read the files into an array in a new program. To get the array into a file, loop through the array while appending each number to a file when looped through until you reach the end.

Answer (score 1):

If the other program is also based on Java, you could leverage the Java Serializable inferface. Here is a tutorial, [Java - Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm).

Answer (score 1):

it would be best to use ObjectOutputStream for the purpose, since the output of the sensor is a integer or double. using writeObject method method your task can be done.

see the link for a detailed reading:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html